# Compilation error when compiling pro*C file with include files not recognizing, even after specifying the ProjectDir (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, proc

I am having hard time in compiling the pro*c files in Visual Studio 2012. It was compiling good in VS 2008. I haven't changed any changes. Most of the problem I see that it is not recognizing the local header file, which has some defines, which is causing this issue.

Here is the example of the compilation error:

```
1>  Semantic error at line 107, column 21, file D:\GC\CoreMSVS2012\Velocity\Common\..\Server\sql\vendors.pc:
1>          int             lv_partner_id[PVU_LOAD_NUM];
1>  ....................1
1>  PCC-S-02322, found undefined identifier
```

where PVU_LOAD_NUM is constant defined in a header file included in vendors.pc file as #include "Vendors.h". This header is in the same location as .pc file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... searched on internet and found no where... not even in their documentation.

Solution:
Whenever you are trying to include environmental variables (like '$(VCInstallDir)') or visual studio variables (like '$(ProjectDir)'), you have use sys_include, not ordinary include. As documentation says to include standard system libraries, I was using this logic for environment variables but not Visual Studio related variables, which caused not working, as it is not evaluated.

Hope someone find it useful, in future.